# HQL query returns fewer results when a return field is added

Tags: hibernate, hql, hibernate-mapping

I'm relatively new to HQL.  Something I'm noticing is that it can return fewer results as you add return fields.

For example, if I run the following query:

```
select cit.noun.value, 
cit.type
from ComponentInventoryType cit 
where 
cit.deleted = false
```

I get more results than if I run this query:

```
select cit.noun.value, 
cit.type,
cit.suffixes.suffix
from ComponentInventoryType cit 
where 
cit.deleted = false
```

And of course the only difference between the two queries is the addition of the cit.suffixes.suffix field.

My first guess is that if suffixes itself is null for any of the entries - it doesn't return the entry at all?

If that is the case - is there any way to get around this so that the field is blank or null - rather than just skipping over the entire entry?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

By adding cit.suffixes.suffix, you've joined from the ComponentInventoryType table to the suffixes table.  I'm guessing that you've mapped a @OneToMany annotation around a set containing suffixes.

From a SQL perspective a straight join from table A to table B on column X won't return a row from A if the join to table B fails (i.e., there's no rows in table B that has a index column of table A in it).

In SQL vernacular, this is a JOIN or NATURAL JOIN situation (depends on whose terminology you want to go by).

In basic SQL, you can use an OUTER JOIN or LEFT OUTER JOIN to allow the joined table (B) to be nulled.

In fact, you can also get more rows when adding suffixes if it's a one-to-many relationship as I intimated above.  So if there are n suffixes for each row in A, then you'd have n*sizeof(A) rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can add check where your field is not equal to null
suffix!=null